# SQL Counting multiple columns for same ID in same table

Tags: sql-server, count, multiple-columns

I have a table with columns `GameID, GoalID, PlayerID, Assist1ID, Assist2ID` (all integers). `PlayerID` translates as the `ID` of the person who actually scored the goal, but `Assist1ID` and `Assist2ID` also get player IDs.

I am trying to get a dataset with the distinct `PlayerID`'s (from the `PlayerID` column or either of the assist columns), a count of goals (`PlayerID` column) and a count of assists (which is actually the sum of counting columns `Assist1` and `Assist2` when that `playerID` occurs). A `PlayerID` will never be in more than one of those columns.

I have been trying several approaches, mostly with UNION ALL, as well as some SUM/CASE but I am just not getting it. Should I be using a temporary table for this, or is there a way to check the rows, and if the `PlayerID`.

Example: (note that `GoalID` and `GameID` aren't really important in this case)

```
GameID | GoalID | PlayerID   | Assist1ID | Assist2ID
  1    |    1   |     1876   |   2098    |     1097 
  1    |    2   |     2098   |   1829    |     1876 
  1    |    3   |     2098   |   1876    |     ----
```

My query should return:

```
PlayerID | Goals   | Assists
 1876    |    1    |    2
 2098    |    2    |    1
 1829    |    0    |    1
 1097    |    0    |    1
```

etc

Is this actually possible, or will I have to do some work in the code part of things?

Comment: You probably have the player ID's in some other table, I assume. You can join the table with this one get counts easily.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I created a SQL fiddle that at least has the schema and sample data for anyone who wants to take a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11e3b/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you get a result record for every player involved, no matter if they only played, only assisted or did both, you must go thrice through your data and glue the records together with UNION ALL. Then count.

```
select playerid, sum(goal) as goals, sum(assist) as assists
from
(
  select playerid, 1 as goal, 0 as assist from mytable
  union all
  select assist1id, 0 as goal, 1 as assist from mytable
  union all
  select assist2id, 0 as goal, 1 as assist from mytable
)
group by playerid;
```

Comment: I tried this one first so I marked it as the correct answer, though I then also tried the other options and CrimsonKing's option gave me the same results as this. I am not sure of the proper ettiquette for assigning marks in a case like that.

Comment: @jungalist Just go with your heart

Answer (score 1):

It can be done this way, but I have a feeling that there might be a simpler solution.

```
SELECT PlayerID, SUM(Goals), SUM(Assists)
FROM (
    SELECT PlayerID,Count(*) AS Goals,0 AS Assists FROM Goals GROUP BY PlayerID UNION ALL
    SELECT Assist1ID,0,Count(*) FROM Goals GROUP BY Assist1ID UNION ALL 
    SELECT Assist2ID,0,Count(*) FROM Goals GROUP BY Assist2ID
) T
WHERE NOT PlayerID IS NULL
GROUP BY PlayerID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.playerid
     , SUM(y.playerid = x.playerid) goals
     , SUM(x.playerid IN (y.assist1id,y.assist2id)) assists
  FROM 
     ( SELECT playerID FROM my_table 
        UNION 
       SELECT assist1id FROM my_table 
        UNION  
       SELECT assist2id FROM my_table
     ) x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON x.playerid IN(y.playerid,y.assist1id,y.assist2id)
 WHERE x.playerid IS NOT NULL
 GROUP
    BY playerid;
```

Comment: This option caused a couple of errors when I tried to execute it. They were:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near 'x'.

There were other parts underlined by the editor as well, but I didn't play around long enough to figure out all of them